# flexbox doesn't exist in safari why?

Tags: safari, flexbox

main container is full page

on all search engine elemenst on website are good positioning but no on safari. Safari dont see css "flex" and i dont know how to fix it

safari dosen't see in css

```
display:flex;
```

and this to

```
display:-webkit-flex;
```

Comment: div.main_container {
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
width: 100%;
}

    enter code here

belka_z_logowaniem is a row with login panel

div.belka_z_logowaniem{
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

Comment: Safari supports `-webkit-flex` and `-webkit-inline-flex` since version 6.1, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137085/flexbox-code-working-on-all-browsers-except-safari-why)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use old version of safari browser?

Make sure that your browser supports flexbox. To check version of browsers see [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)